# How to Join a date filed with a time field in php

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I need to join a date field `bid_staring_date` with a time field `bid_staring_time` and check with current date time `$current_date_time=date('M d,Y H:i:s');` how can I do this?

```
<?php 
    $current_date_time=date('M d,Y H:i:s');
    $bid_schedule_date=date('M d,Y',strtotime($row['bid_staring_date']));
    $bid_schedule_time=date('H:i:s',strtotime($row['bid_staring_time']));
    echo $bid_schedule_date_time=date('M d,Y H:i:s',(strtotime($bid_schedule_date)+strtotime($bid_schedule_time)));
    $bid_schedule_id=$row['bid_schedule_id'];

    if($current_date_time>=$bid_schedule_date_time){
        $btn_type="btn btn-success";
        $btn_value="Bid Now";
        $btn_link="openbid.php?pid=$bid_schedule_id";                                                                       
    } 
    else
    {
        $btn_type="btn btn-danger";
        $btn_value="Bid Not Started";
        $btn_link="#";                                                                      
    }
    echo "<a href='$btn_link' class='$btn_type'>$btn_value</a>";
?>
```

Comment: not clear your question. Do you want  concatenation "(strtotime($bid_schedule_date)+strtotime($bid_schedule_time))"  of this line?

Comment: Store dates and times as a single entity

Comment: 2017-04-22 | 11:56:00 |  00:30:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I need to also get top largest 5 bid_rate for each bid_shedule_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGwAR.png)

[SELECT * FROM `tbl_bid_history` ORDER BY bid_rate DESC limit 3

this query returns only top 5 values of same bid_shedule_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQbmc.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16270522)

Comment: Sorry, Which is the link??

Answer (score 0):

```
   $game_date = game['date'];
   $game_time = game['time'];

    $combined_date_and_time = $game_date . ' ' . $game_time;
    $past_date = strtotime($combined_date_and_time);
```

reference :: [Take two variables for Date and Time and combine to make one date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692704/take-two-variables-for-date-and-time-and-combine-to-make-one-date)